# Unable to pass React prop to Axios get for API call

Tags: reactjs

My file structure is as follows :
src > components, where App.js is in src, and both Geo.js and Temp.js are in components (sibling components). App.js calls Geo.js. Geo.js calls Temp.js in its return function, like `<Temp lat={this.state.latitude} lon={this.state.longitude} />`

The idea is, I will pull the longitude and latitude with an API in Geo.js (successfully working), and then pass the lat and lon into Temp.js as props, to be passed through a weather API.

I've successfully passed through the two props into Temp.js, and the {this.props.lat}/{this.props.lon} returns the correctly passed prop values in my render function, but it still returns undefined in my Axios get call. I'm not sure why the prop is passing properly, but not being registered in the API call?

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Temp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lat: this.props.lat,
      lon: this.props.lon,
      temp: null,
      wind: null,
    };
  }
  getTempInfo = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.props.lat}&lon=${this.props.lon}&appid={mytopsecretAPIkeyyyy}`
      ) {/* Not successful, returning undefined for both lat and lon */}
      .then((response) => {
        let data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          temp: data.main.temp,
          wind: data.wind.speed,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTempInfo();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Temp: {this.state.temp}</p> {/* Returns null as per initial state, as API call doesn't work */}
        <p>Wind: {this.state.wind}</p> {/* Returns null as per initial state, as API call doesn't work */}
        <p>Lat from prop : {this.props.lat}</p> {/* Successful */}
        <p>Lon from prop : {this.props.lon}</p> {/* Successful */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Temp;
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Please try to `console.log(this.props.lat, this.props.lon)` in `componentDidMount` to check if they are passed correctly

Comment: @FirstArachne tried to console.log those two in componentDidMount and they also both returned as undefined. Is there a way to ensure it passes? I'm not sure why it'd work in render(), but not in componentDidMount.

Comment: Can you show where the `Temp` component gets rendered?

Comment: @Amy if they are undefined at first but then get defined later that will be reflected in `render` and not in `componentDidMount`.  Maybe you need a function component with a `useEffect` that fetches once you receive a defined value for both?

Comment: Also you do not want to put `lat` and `lon` in `state` since they are already in `props`.

Comment: Does this work? https://pastebin.com/npU5qr4u

Comment: @LindaPaiste Yes, it did work! You're amazing - thank you! I appreciate you explaining it too :)